# Retrieve printer driver version with Powershell PrintManagement cmdlets?

Tags: powershell, printer, wmi

The version numbers in the gui look like 10.0.17134.1 and 3.0.8.0 but their equivalents (?) from the `Get-PrinterDriver`-cmdlet look at least cryptic:

```
Get-PrinterDriver | Select-Object Name, MajorVersion, DriverVersion
```

gives me an output like this:

```
Name                   MajorVersion    DriverVersion
----                   ------------    -------------
Microsoft XPS Docu...             4 2814750890000385
Samsung Universal ...             3  844424930656256
```

So do I really need to use the WMI/CIM cmdlets to get the *real* version numbers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because `Get-PrinterDriver`'s `DriverVersion` is of type [UInt64](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uint64?view=netframework-4.7.2):

[image]

A breakout way to fix this is to use the below ([source](https://gist.github.com/janegilring/6486669)). I hope there is a more elegant way of recasting these values in the format we expect, though I appreciate how transparent this method is to best understand what is going on.

```
Get-PrinterDriver | Select-Object Name,@{
    n="DriverVersion";e={

        $ver = $_.DriverVersion
        $rev = $ver -band 0xffff
        $build = ($ver -shr 16) -band 0xffff
        $minor = ($ver -shr 32) -band 0xffff
        $major = ($ver -shr 48) -band 0xffff
        "$major.$minor.$build.$rev"

    }
}
```

The first result of this when run on my machine is:

```
Name                                                    DriverVersion 
----                                                    ------------- 
Send to Microsoft OneNote 16 Driver                     16.0.7629.4000
```

The conversion works by using [bitwise operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation) to evaluate each `DriverVersion` (64bit) in sections of 16 bits to determine the major, minor, build, and revision numbers.

For example, the first `DriverVersion` on my machine, as a 64bit number, is `4503600127348640`. Here is the [bitwise AND](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#AND) (`-band`) happening during the definition of the `$rev` variable, shown in binary:

```
‭00010000000000000000000000011101110011010000111110100000‬ (4503600127348640)
                                        1111111111111111 (65535, aka "0xffff")
                                    =   0000111110100000 (4000)
                                                         (DriverVersion = X.Y.Z.4000)
```

Here is `$build`, which also uses `-shr` ([bit shift-right](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_arithmetic_operators?view=powershell-6#long-description)):

```
‭00010000000000000000000000011101110011010000111110100000‬ (4503600127348640)
                        1111111111111111                 (65535)
                    =   0001110111001101                 (7629)
                                                         (DriverVersion = X.Y.7629.4000)
```

Here is `$minor`:

```
‭00010000000000000000000000011101110011010000111110100000‬ (4503600127348640)
        1111111111111111                                 (65535)
    =   0000000000000000                                 (0)
                                                         (DriverVersion = X.0.7629.4000)
```

Finally, `$major`:

```
00010000000000000000000000011101110011010000111110100000‬ (4503600127348640)
11111111                                                 (65535)
00010000                                                 (16)
                                                         (DriverVersion = 16.0.7629.4000)
```

Comment: I see. So highest possible version would be 65535.65535.65535.65535 - should actually be enough for a printer driver... - thanks, nice answer.

Answer (score 1):

There is a lot of room for arguing about what is elegant, what is expressive, what is concise, what is cryptic a.s.o. - A certainly more brief - not necessarily in any way better - version would be the following:

```
Get-PrinterDriver | Select-Object Name, @{ 
  n = "DriverVersion"
  e = {
        $ver = $_.DriverVersion
        (3..0 | ForEach-Object { ($ver -shr ($_ * 16)) -band 0xffff }) -join '.'
      }
}
```

Just another way to Rome.

Comment: Excellent.  I'm PDQ Inventory to catalog the drivers in our environment, and this was the missing piece.